# How to implement Kahn's algorithm for a topological sort in rust?

Tags: rust

I want to implement Kahn's algorithm for a directed acyclic graph.

I understand why in rust it's not possible to borrow mutable variables more than once and that I cannot borrow mutable var if it was already borrowed immutable, but I don't want to use a ref counting pointer because it allocates memory on a heap.

```rust
struct Node {
    ref_count: u32,
    id: usize,
    text: String
}

impl Node {
    fn new(text: String) -> Self {
        Node {
            ref_count: 0,
            id: 0,
            text: text
        }
    }

    fn get_ref_count(&self) -> u32 {
        self.ref_count
    }

    fn get_id(&self) -> usize {
        self.id
    }

    fn execute(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.text);
    }
}

struct Edge {
    from: usize,
    to: usize
}

impl Edge {
    fn new(from: &Node, to: &Node) -> Self {
        Edge {
           from: from.get_id(),
           to: to.get_id() 
        }
    }
}

struct Dag {
    nodes: Vec<Node>,
    edges: Vec<Edge>
}

impl Dag {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Dag {
            nodes: vec![],
            edges: vec![]
        }
    }

    fn add_node(&mut self, node: Node) {
        let id = self.nodes.len();
        self.nodes.push(node);
        self.nodes[id].id = id;
    }

    fn add_edge(&mut self, edge: Edge) {
        self.edges.push(edge);
    }

    fn sort_and_execute(&mut self) {
        for edge in &self.edges {
            let node = &mut self.nodes[edge.to];
            node.ref_count+=1;
        }

        let mut stack: Vec<&Node> = vec![];
        for node in &self.nodes {
            if node.get_ref_count() == 0 {
                stack.push(node);
            }
        }

        while !stack.is_empty() {
            let node = stack.pop();
            if let Some(node) = node {
                node.execute();
                let edges: Vec<&Edge> = self.edges
                    .iter()
                    .filter(|edge| edge.from == node.get_id() )
                    .collect();
                for edge in edges {
                    //linked node must be mutable, because the ref count has to be decremented
                    let linkedNode = &mut self.nodes[edge.to];
                    linkedNode.ref_count -= 1;
                    if linkedNode.get_ref_count() == 0 {
                        stack.push(linkedNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Node::new("0".to_owned());
    let b = Node::new("1".to_owned());
    let c = Node::new("2".to_owned());
    let d = Node::new("3".to_owned());

    let a_c = Edge::new(&a, &c);
    let b_c = Edge::new(&b, &c);
    let c_d = Edge::new(&c, &d);

    let mut dag = Dag::new();
    dag.add_node(a);
    dag.add_node(b);
    dag.add_node(c);
    dag.add_node(d);

    dag.add_edge(a_c);
    dag.add_edge(b_c);
    dag.add_edge(c_d);
    
    dag.sort_and_execute();
}
```

The problem is that in line `73` the for loop borrows `self.nodes` to find nodes with `ref_count = 0` and in line `89` `self.nodes` also has to be borrowed (mutably) to decrement the ref count

is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Note that `Vec` also allocates memory on the heap. That being said, you can use [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) which uses the memory of wherever you put it (e.g. stack for a local variable, heap for a `Box<RefCell<_>>`, directly in the array for an array or a `Vec<RefCell<_>>`).

Comment: Yes, that's correct that `Vec` also allocated memory on the heap, but to process this algorithm there has to be some kind of storage. The problem is that in line`73`, the for loop borrows  `self.nodes` and in line `89` `self.nodes` has to be borrowed mutably to decrement the ref count

Comment: If you change `self.nodes` to a `Vec<RefCell<Node>>`, then you can do `node.borrow_mut().ref_count += 1;` even if `self.nodes` is borrowed in the `for` loop.

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought you meant the `stack` to be a `RefCell`. My bad. I'll check it out in a minute. Thanks

Comment: Is it ok for the `stack` variable be `Vec<Ref<Node>>` and then push into this vector like this:
`stack.push(node.borrow());`? Does `Ref<Node>` in this scenario also use stack?

Comment: Note that storing a `Ref<Node>` somewhere will prevent you from doing a `borrow_mut` elsewhere. You should probably have the `stack` variable be a `Vec<&RefCell<Node>>` so that you only `.borrow()` or `.borrow_mut()` the nodes when you need to access their contents. Either way the nodes themselves are only stored in `self.nodes` and the `stack` variable only holds references.

Comment: We can't see line numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on [interior mutability](https://ricardomartins.cc/2016/06/08/interior-mutability) in more detail to be able to implement this idiomatically. While `RefCell` is a possible solution to this problem, it can be made simpler and possibly less computationally expensive if you use a [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html), or even an [`AtomicU32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicU32.html) depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this by using `Vec<usize>` (node.get_id()) instead of `Vec<&Node>` for the variable `stack`.